# How does a message get back to a spammer?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I know that replying to a spammer is not a good idea. But I've always wondered how does a spammer receive the reply? I know that the data in the email header can be spoofed. And I can decipher some of the header info.

In the case I'm interested in, the spammer seems to be using the email address of someone I know. The owner of that email address is not seeing the messages from or to the spammer in their account. How can that happen? I've looked at the email headers and can see the path the message took to be received. Except for the last part. The node in the first Received: header does not exist (unknown node via nslookup) Also I can't detect any thing in the Return-Path: address or the From: address fields that indicates how the reply is getting back to the sender.

Is anyone able to answer that? I'd really appreciate it.

BYW, I told the original owner to change their password, just in case the email account was compromised.

Comment: "*the spammer seems to be using the email address of someone I know. The owner of that email address is not seeing the messages from or to the spammer in their account. How can that happen?*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing

Comment: that person you know had a device infected with malware at some point and the malware stole the address book

Comment: Thank you Gantendo. This is the type of info I was seeking. A more complete description of the scenario is that I received an email supposedly from a friend, just saying 'How are you?'. The email address looked right, so I replied. Then I got a reply from them asking for money. That's when I knew it was a scammer. Looking through the headers, I couldn't figure out how my reply was getting back to the spammer and not showing up in the friends account.

Comment: Aha, the infamous "friend in need" scam. It has been extremely profitable.

Answer (score 2):

Do not even bother. There is no practical way you can get back to them. They will ignore you or (in the very unlikely event they saw you) send you more spam.

Delete the spam, blacklist it if you can, and move on.

Comment: It seems like the question is about how a spammer would get a reply in order to confirm a mail adress is valid and read and also an easy target for spam, what makes such an address mor valuable. Common cases i know want the recepient to click a link or see an attachment, but maybe there are spam mails out there demanding a reply in order to get this nigerian batzillions. What's the matter with such mails if no return path exists?

Comment: Yes, I know that a link or attachment is the usual way the spammer determines an active email. But in this case is was a simple 'How are you?" email from a known email address. (I know, email addresses are easily spoofed.) yea, when they asked for money, I'm outta there.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the aim of such messages is to make you click on a link or to
open some infected document or image (even images can be infected).

Sometimes the aim is simply to find out if you exist and if you're
looking at such emails. The email will include some innocent-looking
image whose URL will contain a parameter that includes your
identification in the spammer's database, so just by displaying
the email you confirm your existence.

In any case, the spammer is usually not looking to getting a return
email, since using a funny return address might raise some alarm
by your spam filter or other security software.
The return address will in most cases truly be your friend's,
who will not at all understand your return email.

Comment: Important sidenote: This is why you should disable showing images in emails. The spammers know if you've opened their spam if images are enabled.

Comment: Decent mail clients disable loading images that weren't embedded into email itself or from untrusted sources.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Correct. But many people use mail clients that are far from perfect (and/or configured incorrectly).

Comment: I am very aware of these techniques to try and avoid spam. And I only get a few true spam messages a week.

Comment: I also know that if someone sends a 'blast-o-gram' to many people, say from a club, they should put the addresses in the BCC field. But some don't and I tell them I don't appreciate my email being blasted to people I don't know. All it takes is one of those computers to be compromised and I'm possibly opened up to more spam.

Comment: So here is the point: promote those clients. I should name Thunderbird, it does it right.