# Is it possible to set outgoing emails to forward via a second email account?

Tags: email

I'm hoping someone can give me some understanding of the possibilities of email forwarding.  Let's define the intended recipient's true email address <good-at-gmail.com> and a scammers email address <bad-at-outlook.com>. An email is sent from bad-at-outlook.com.  I reply to this email and receive a reply from the intended recipient,
However, the reply came from <bad-at-outlook.com>!

I can understand if the scammer set up email forwarding from 'bad@outlook.com' to 'good@gmail.com' so that my emails will reach the intended recipient.

But, if the intended recipient replied from <good-at-gmail.com>, I would expect this to show in the emails I received from him, and not from <bad-at-outlook.com>.

Is there any way that the intended recipient could send emails from <good-at-gmail.com> but unknown to him, have them automatically routed through <bad-at-outlook.com> and onwards to his customers?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a message get back to a spammer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1802667/how-does-a-message-get-back-to-a-spammer)

Comment: Is there actually a scammer involved or is it your assumption.  This behaviour can happen by having a different `reply-to` and `sender` addresses.

Comment: Yes there is. It turns out there is a way to forward emails via a different account. The scammer exploited this to see messages going between customers and the builder.